# Storing Values to a 2 dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Brand new to Java.

I'm trying to store values from a String to a 2D array in java. The first two values of my String give me rows and columns for a grid. From here, I need to use Integer.parseInt() to parse the values and assign them. I'm attempting do this using a for() loop, but I'm completely stuck. Here's what I have so far (notes included to indicate what I'm attempting to acheive):

```
    int r = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    rows = r;

    int c = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    cols = c;

    // create 2D array of int values
    // place the reference to the array object in grid variable

    int[][] input = new int[rows][cols];
    grid = input;

    //parse then store remaining values as int values in the 2D array using a nested loop

    for(int i = 0 ; i < tokens.length ; i++) {

        // read the next value and assign to next token
    }
```

Comment: What is tokens?

Comment: 'tokens' is a String or an array? What is the format of your input String?

Comment: tokens obviously is an array since we have tokens[0]/tokens[1]/tokens.length in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be a bit off - you parse those numbers into int variables `r` and `c` but then do `int[][] input = new int[rows][cols];`. You don't have such variables as `rows` and `cols`.

Also you should not start with 0 in your loop since values `tokens[0]` and `tokens[1]` are for row and column counts.

Start loop at 2, or end it with `tokens.length-2` and add 2 every time you take value from `tokens` inside the loop.

In order to calculate the row and column index you need to take your `i` (e.g. index in `tokens` array), adjust for the aforementioned offset of 2, floor-divide by column count to receive row number, and get a remainder of division by column count to get row number.

E.g.

```
for(int i = 2 ; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   int value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
   int idx = i-2;
   int row = Math.floorDiv(idx, c);
   int col = idx % c;
   grid[row][col] = value;
}
```